# Node.- issues when trying to request behind https proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https, request

I am trying to download an image from a server through an https proxy, please help.

My code:

```
var request = require('request');
  request({
   url: url,
   proxy: proxy
   }, function (err, res, imgBuffer) {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(res)
   })
```

The error:
    `Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown   protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:827:`

I can provide any additional info needed, I have already tried a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you need to change the config file in npm.

Check out this tutorial: https://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-a-corporate-proxy/

Go down to the section titled "NPM configuration."

Comment: Sorry, that might not be what I am looking for, my code is designed to use 1 of about 5 proxies depending on the situation, this is using a corporate proxy for npm, which I do not need, what I need is for the get request to go through a proxy.